# Is reputation auto-updating now?

Tags: discussion, reputation, ajax

I'm trying to work out whether or not I'm imagining a newly-implemented feature.

I'm pretty sure that I've just gone back to a tab where I previous had reputation X (on the questions page), and seen it change to reputation X+10 in the background.

This would certainly be a neat feature, using the same sort of ajax approach as the background checks for new answers being posted to questions. However, I'm slightly unsure as to whether I'm just imagining it or not.

Has anyone else seen this? If I'm right, does anyone know how long the feature's been there?

Comment: It's probably only Skeet-enabled.

Comment: ...are votes auto-updating now? (On Meta, I'm kind of sure vote counts are updated with some web sockets magic nowadays.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say you are imagining things.

Firebug will have stayed open 5 minutes by the time I finish writing this, and I see no ajax requests at all. So, either you're spending too much time here and you started hallucinating, or it waits so long in between ajax requests that this feature would be useless.

Comment: I think it's very likely that I had refreshed the page or moved onto a different set of results without noticing. Maybe I should turn this question into a feature request :)

Comment: I vote for "spending too much time"!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think I've experienced that, too.

I'm sure the screen has magically updated once or twice while I was looking at it.

I just told myself it was wishful thinking: the excesses of an overheated imagination.