# Feature request Ajax reputation auto updating

Tags: feature-request, ajax

Sometimes I refresh a page *if I can't find any questions to answer* to see if my reputation has increased.  Or if I spend a long time anwswering a question, it would be great if rep autoupdated.  <del>Would probably save some bandwidth too.</del>

This was mentioned before but not as a feature request.

[Is reputation auto-updating now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37403/150915)

Comment: How can you find questions to answer without refreshing the page?

Comment: If I click on a question and don't end up answering I click back which doesn't refresh the page

Comment: ...and then you click another one and see the fresh score on top! ;-)

Comment: You got me on that one. Question edited...:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this feature is due to be implemented - although if someone else knows different then please correct me.

However, a user script has been created to auto update your reputation.  It is called [SO Live! and can be found on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/1703/so-live-live-updates-to-your-reputation-score).